# Как использовать Switch от Android 5 в Android 4?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-material, android-style, android-switch

Как использовать `Switch` от Android 5 в Android 4? Громадный `Switch` от 4го Android'a совсем никак не вписывается в мой дизайн!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил stacktrace. И давайте удалим ненужные комменты.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, уже лучше! Ошибки нет. Только вот и `Switch` пропал... Его тупо нет!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я добавил фото...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, рылся и нашел в гугле вопрос, почему не отображается `Switch`. Оказывается, ему нужна тема `Theme.AppCompat`, а у меня `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`. буду пробовать подключить Вашу либу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ух ты! А классная библиотека!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, заработало! В ответ!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, либа.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: если вы всё существенное распределили в вопрос и ответ, то уже, пожалуй, можно удалять )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, согласен)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения сей задачи можно воспользоваться вот этой библиотекой: [Material](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Switch)

В разметке это будет примерно так:

```
<com.rey.material.widget.Switch
    style="@style/Material.Widget.Switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

А на устройстве так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ещё можно попробовать гугловый виджет из библиотеки поддержки : [SwitchCompat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html)

В разметку добавлять надо так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/Switch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff=""
    android:text="Toggle Switch"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
    android:textOn=""
    android:button="@null"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
```

и не забывать наследовать тему приложения от `Theme.AppCompat`

Пример на англо-саксонском: [Material Toggle switch using appcompat-v7](http://takeoffandroid.com/android-views/material-toggle-switch-using-appcompat-v7/)

Comment: Хотел спросить, а почему Вы англо-саксонский называете англо-саксонским?)

Comment: @bukashka101, это я так ненавязчиво политоту пложу) Не обращайте внимания)